# Rails - .where method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I have the following code in my top navigation menu:

```
<% if current_user.relationships.where(state: 'active') %>
    <li><%= link_to 'New Schedule', new_schedule_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Users have_many relationships.  'state' is a column in the relationships table.  I only want the link to appear if the user has a relationship where the value of the state column is set to 'active'.  For some reason, This link is appearing to user's who do not have relationship with state = active.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it to

```
current_user.relationships.where(state: 'active').exists?
```

or

```
current_user.relationships.where(state: 'active').first
```

`current_user.relationships.where(state: 'active')` will return an ActiveRelation object, and it is not evaluated to false in Ruby. Only `nil` of `false` is

Comment: @Philip7899 No, It just returns an ActiveRelation object. There is no `SQL` query happening until you call `exists?` or `first` or `each` on the the object, lazyloading!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
current_user.relationships.where(state: 'active').any?
```

Since even if there are no relationships, the where method will still return an empty array, which is not nil.